# Can I jaywalk without getting into trouble?

Tags: yo-kai-watch

If I cross against the light while walking or biking enough times, Snartle appears and basically kills my whole team.

Is there a way to be able to cross at marked crossings without having to stop for the light? Or am I stuck being a good citizen if I want to avoid Snartle?

Answer (score 1):

Ironically you can jaywalk without consequences by crossing the road anywhere there is no crosswalk. You can't be hit by cars and it is often faster than pressing the button and waiting at a crosswalk.